# No restart in stopwatch

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, stopwatch

in MonoDevelop fro Unity I'm using C# to develop my "great" game. I'm using stopwatch there, and funny enough there isn't restart method in this class even though it is listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx#Y292

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have not experience with MonDevelop, but I know it targets multiple non-Windows platforms. So, the question is if you are targeting Microsoft's .Net platform? If your targeting Mono perhaps you should check their documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stopwatch.Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart.aspx) documentation clearly suggests that this method is available in .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.

Seems like you are targetting to .NET runtime lower than .NET 4.0

Comment: Downvoted because you didnt mention a proper solution other than re-targeting to new .Net version. The answer by @Darren Davies includes this answer + how to do it with older .Net versions.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using .Net 4.0? That method appears to be only in .Net 4.0/4.5. Anything prior you should use the `Reset()` method.

Comment: I've just downgraded a project from 4.0 to 2.0 (living in the past?), and to get it to work I had to replace Stopwatch.Restart() with Stopwatch.Reset() plus Stopwatch.Start().